# Which one will execute first if we submit two tasks to same dispatchqueue?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

Created Custom dispatch queue and submitted two tasks to same queue and I gave sleep(3) for first task and sleep(1) for second task. then why first task completes execution first?

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "name");

queue.async {

    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)

    print("Task1 done")
}

queue.async {

    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)

    print("Task2 done")
}
```

Comment: Because by default dispatch queues are serial dispatch queues. The first task must complete before the second can start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for them to execute in a `concurrent` manner u have to use `attributes: .concurrent` as follows.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "name", attributes: .concurrent);

queue.async {
    
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
    
    print("Task1 done")
}

queue.async {
    
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    
    print("Task2 done")
}
```

If you omit that part, the dispatch queue executes tasks serially. That is what you are experiencing.

Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300059-init).

> The attributes to associate with the queue. Include the concurrent attribute to create a dispatch queue that executes tasks concurrently. If you omit that attribute, the dispatch queue executes tasks serially.